# Send Email content(with HTML tags) Windows 8.1 Universal application

Tags: c#, email, windows-8.1-universal

I'm working on a Windows 8.1 Universal application. I do have a requirement to send email through my application. The content I am taking from DB has HTML tags(Example attached). I need to open the browser with this content loaded and recognized with HTML pattern in the Body Content of the mail browser. I'm using `Launcher.LaunchUriAsync()` method to open the default browser.

Please suggest me to include the content(with html tags) in the browser.

PS: I tried with Chrome,Outlook. Both renders HTML content as is without recognizing it as HTML styles. [image]

Comment: Save it to a html file and use the Launcher to open the file instead opening by protocol?

Comment: I need to fill To field, Subject field, Body field(with HTML content). All these fields should be editable. Will this be possible by opening a html file? Its a email template which opens in the default browser which the user can further edit and send the same.

Comment: There is no "Windows 8.1 UWP application". UWP means Universal Windows Platform which is [introduced in Windows 10](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/universal-application-platform-guide). So a UWP app always represents a Windows 10 app. For Windows 8.1 Universal app, we can use [tag:windows-8.1-universal].

Comment: Ok @Scavenger. Thanks for your edits. Do you have any idea on achieving this in Windows 8.1 application?